# Best Flash Engine for Vector Graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector, game-engine, movieclip

Hi can anyone give me a link to a flash library that can use vector images or merge with flash profressional cs6 movieclips?

Vector images made in Illustrator or Flash Pro CS6?

Would cs6 profressional native be enough to make a 'optimized' game? using less memory etc.

I'm looking for a flash game engine that I can still code for like FlashDevelop and Flashpunk but can do vector graphics as well.

Comment: Flash uses vector graphics, anyway, so you don't per se need an additional library. You can also import Illustrator documents into Flash. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: You can always look into frameworks like Starling.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a few things to be aware of:

- Flash supports vector graphics. This is implemented in the base code of the language, and thus you will be able to use vector graphics no matter what you are doing (though some prebuilt engines will require raster images instead for various reasons)
- FlashDevelop is in IDE, or Integrated Development Environment, which means that it is a tool, like notepad or microsoft word, but in which you type your code. It is not a game engine.
- As it seems you've discovered, Flashpunk is designed for raster graphics, not vector graphics.
- How "optomized" your game ultimately turns out is a result of you, not the tools you are using. If you use art assets with thousands of vertices in your vector graphics there is no code base in the world that will save your game from being unoptimized. So yes, you can make a fully optimized game using just Flash CS6
- Flash CS6 is really two things in one: Content creation tool (for making or grouping art assets) and an Actionscript Integrated Development Environment.

Keeping all this in mind, you can indeed develop content in flash, then export that content from flash to FlashDevelop. The prefered way to do this is SWC importing. Basically, you build a .fla file in Flash with all your graphics and sound, **assign a class name to each flash DisplayObject in your library you want to use in FlashDevelop**, go into publish settings in flash and enable .swc output, and publish. Then import it in FlashBuilder and you can simply call

```
this.addChild(new graphic001())
```

Within a class you have written in flash builder (one that extends DisplayObjectContainer, of course).

A good example tutorial can be found: [Here](http://cote.cc/blog/linking-swc-files-in-your-actionscript-editor)

To answer your original question though, just in case I'm wrong and you **are** ready for this (or the next guy to view this question is), I'd recommend using the Citrus Engine. Nape physics engine is pretty easy to work with and once you're feeling confident with the traditional displayList format you can begin using the starling framework without having to switch to a different engine. However I would like to point out that I really don't think you're quite ready to do this quite yet. It may be best for you to work through a couple of "make a game" flash tutorials first, such as [this one](http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-make-a-vertical-shooter-in-as3-part-1/).